# Why does two way binding sometimes work without using a dot in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Consider this fiddle: [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/Qvu5u/1/) When you select a date, you will notice that the text above it is not updating. This is because I had to use an object in my list, like this: [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Qvu5u/3/) (simplified).

But, on the other hand, this does work, without a dot: [Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/DnKs5//)

Could someone explain what the difference is between fiddle 1 and fiddle 3? I've read about prototypical inheritance ([unerstanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)), but I don't understand this behavior.

Fiddle 3:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!


  <button ng-click="visible = !visible">Toggle</button>

  <div ng-show="visible">
    Some content 
    <sample visible="visible"></sample>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.visible = true;
}

myApp.directive("sample", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span ng-click="hide()" style="cursor: pointer;">X</span>',
        scope:{
            visible: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            scope.hide = function(){
                console.log(scope.visible);
                scope.visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you really intend to put the first `</div>` just after the `Hello ...` line?  That means the rest of the HTML is outside MyCtrl's scope.

Comment: @MarkRajcok You're right. I've placed everything within the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your directive creates an isolate scope (and there are no intermediate scopes), and it uses `=` for two-way databinding, you don't need to use object properties – i.e., you don't need a "dot" to get it to work.

In Fiddle 1 and 2, ng-repeat is creating an intermediate (child) scope that prototypically inherits from the MyCtrl scope.  In this case, you need to use object properties.

Answer (score 0):

The `Fiddle3` makes sense since it tries to hide itself and all variables are in its own isolated scope.

It will be more comparable to `Fiddle1` if you want to implement something like **when click on X, trigger the `Toggle` button to hide `sample` control**. Because in `Fiddle1` you actually wanted to figure out how to modify the value outside the isolated scope, rather than inside the scope created by the directive.

Comment: I've updated my fiddle, it wasn't correct. My point now is, in the directive I can manipulate the `visible` variable of the `MyCtrl` controller, without using a dot. When I hit the X not only the sample tag hides, but also the containt div, since this has a ng-show set to visible. I hope you understand my point :)