# Angular $scope variable not found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I am using google-places directive and everything was Ok, but I suddenly noticed that my variable $scope.location is not defined in controller. But in the view it is available?

What is wrong? thanks

```
yuppiApp.directive('googlePlaces', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        replace:true,
        scope: {location:'='},
        template: "<input id='google_places_ac' ng-model='google_map' name='map' type='text' required/>",
        link: function($scope, elm, attrs){
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#google_places_ac")[0], {});
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                $scope.location = place.geometry.location.lat() + ',' + place.geometry.location.lng();
                console.log($scope.location); 
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Code from view:

```
{{ location }}

<google-places location="location"></google-places>
```

Code from controller:

```
$scope.addNew = function () {
    console.log("Location: " + $scope.location);
};
```

I called console.log($scope) in both cases in directive and in controller and it looks like there two versions of $scope. I don't understand why.

```
Object { $id: "0U8", $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, .......
Object { $id: "00M", this: Object, $$listeners: Object
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't creating or assigning $scope.location somewhere else?

Comment: I am using it in controller's function that call on button click. It works before, but I don't know what changed exactly. I am still new to angular but not completely new.

Comment: Why do you have to do `location="location"` when you are not using 2 way binding

Comment: Can you post more of your code from the controller?

Comment: actually I used it before, there was an attribute in directive scope: {location:'='}, but removed it because I don't understand why it was there.

Comment: @user1315599 It was there because that is what is called 2-way binding in an isolated scoped directive.

Comment: hold the phone, you removed a scope declaration because you "didn't understand why it was there", and now you're asking why an assignment to a scope isn't working?  Does it work if you put the declaration back?

Comment: No, it doesn't, I've added it back, but when have published on stackoverlow forgot to add it back. I will change it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does two way binding sometimes work without using a dot in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024809/why-does-two-way-binding-sometimes-work-without-using-a-dot-in-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using this directive inside another directive in your template, and that directive is creating a child scope. Then you end up with two scopes, and that googlePlaces directive writes it to child scope, inaccessible directly to controller.

Change your code like this:

Add location again to your directive to become an isolated scope:

```
yuppiApp.directive('googlePlaces', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
          location: '='
        }
        ...
```

Code from view:

```
{{ data.location }}

<google-places location="data.location"></google-places>
```

Code from controller:

```
$scope.data = {
 location: null
};
```

This way both scopes will share the same object variable. This is tht 'dot' rule applied (all bindings should have a . in it).

I'd suggest you to learn about controllerAs syntax for your controllers and isolated scope on directives.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But I don't understand what was the difference. I hope after reading about controllerAs everything will be clear.

Comment: the problem is called scope inheritance. for sure, controllerAs is a simple and effective way to ban this kind of problems (it's a trap for beginners)

Comment: @Werlang fyi.. You do not really need to ensure dot rule when using 2-way binding, that is the whole purpose of two way binding. But the tricky thing about it is that you will see the consumed scope property getting updated only after the digest cycle that updates 2-way bound property, A best approach here would be to use an `ng-model` and set viewValue of it and also use function binding say `onPlaceChanged` and trigger it off after setting the model. _Clean contract is what you will get with that_

Comment: @PSL that would be another approach. post that as answer if you will. about the dot rule, this is already settled question. it is almost obligatory to understand, but we're all for maintainable programs and easy to reason about, imho.

Comment: @PSL google-places looks like a black box component to me, that could be reused in many places. an isolated scope is better because a) the component wouldn't mess with its parent scope, and b) we can name our models whatever we want in parent scope. It gives that clean contract you refer.

Comment: @Werlang It is a complete misconception saying that a component will be reusable only if it is isolated scoped (how many angular built in directives are isolate scoped? aren't they reusable?). You are not messing with the parent scope (_explicitly_) anyways . And with your approach you are messing with parent scope property anyways with 2-way binding, just that it is abstracted out in the 2-way binding logic. I did not see what is the point you are trying to make there.

Comment: @Werlang Just my opinion and i would not use isolated scope for this because the parent scope really does not set the location, instead it is set only by the directive. But as you said earlier, major issue was how the directive was being used. So this discussion is probably irrelevant anyways.